# WebAPI OData routing: parameterized prefix in odataPath

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

for a WebAPI 2 OData solution we need to be able to map the following route-type:

*~/odata/1234erp/Products* meaning a value prefixes the Controller (or Entityset) segment. Ive got my route set up as follows:

```
    config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
        routeName: "odata",
        routePrefix: "odata/{tableid}/{controller}", 
        model: ModelBuilder.GetEdmModel(), 
        pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
        routingConventions: conventions);
```

This makes the SelectAction method in my CustomControllerRoutingConvention get hit (the SelectController does not get hit) but the odataPath parameter counts 0 segments, where i'd hope it would recognize something like *~/tableid/entityset/*

Now i can probably solve this using something like

```
controllerContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["tableid"]
```

but is there a better (typesafer?) solution for this?

*EDIT:*
Also, since `ODataPath path = Request.GetODataPath()` returns 0 segments, it's no longer possible to derive the EdmType neccessary for ODataQueryOptions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking off the {controller} segment of the routePrefix like this: `"odata/{tableid}` 
seems to solve this. Now i can direct to the correct controller like this

```
    if (firstSegment != null && firstSegment is EntitySetPathSegment)
    {
        return firstSegment.ToString();
    }
```

And in that controller i can get the tableid as a parameter: `Get(string tableid)`

Better yet,

```
ODataPath path = Request.GetODataPath();
IEdmType edmType = path.EdmType;
```

returns the correct EdmType...

Comment: although this works, i haven't figured out how to 'extract' the tableid in a type-safe manner when im in the controller. i can do it like this:

`var tableid = ControllerContext.Request.RequestUri.Segments[2].TrimEnd('/');`

but thats not ideal. anyway to do this in a type-safe manner?